# flutter firebase streambuilder gives returned null error

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am trying to read data realtime from my firebase firestore database through flutter. I learned that the best way to manage this is streambuilder. Checked a few sites on this topic and made a code like below and put a print statement just to see if everything works ok, however when i run the program it give the fallowing errors:

```
A build function returned null.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> file:///C:/Users/faruk/Desktop/3-sayiavi/sayi_avi/lib/gamescreen.dart:116:15

The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("status")
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> file:///C:/Users/faruk/Desktop/3-sayiavi/sayi_avi/lib/gamescreen.dart:116:15
```

My Code is below:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'numbers.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


Numbers myNumbers = Numbers();

void main(){
  runApp(
      GameScreen()
  );
}
class GameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id ='gamescreen';
  @override
  _GameScreenState createState() => _GameScreenState();
}

class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> {
  final _auth =FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;
  final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  String collectionPath = 'users';
  String docPath;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }
  
  void getCurrentUser() async{
    try{
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if(user !=null){
        loggedInUser =user;
        docPath = loggedInUser.uid;
        print(docPath);
        print(collectionPath);
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }


  Expanded attachNumber(imagenumber){
    return Expanded(
      child:FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[1]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage1'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[1] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[2]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage2'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[2] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[3]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage3'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[3] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[4]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage4'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[4] =true;
            }
          });
          final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
          assetsAudioPlayer.open(
            Audio("assets/audios/click.wav"),
          );
        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: Image.asset('images/$imagenumber'),
      ),
    );
  }

  FlatButton showDeleteNumbers(statusNumber,number){
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          myNumbers.numberStatus[statusNumber] =false;
          myNumbers.buttonValues[number] = 'nonumber.png';
        });
      },
      child: Image.asset('images/'+myNumbers.buttonValues['$number']),
      //todo: _auth.signOut(); ekleyerek signout yapacaz
      //Navigator.pop(context); bir önceki ekrana dönecez;
    );
  }





  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
          title: Text('Sayı Avı Oyun Ekranı'),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _firestore.collection(collectionPath).document(docPath).snapshots(),
          builder: (context,snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              var userDocument = snapshot.data;
              print(userDocument['status']);
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 80,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 50,
                          child: Column(
                            children: myNumbers.getUserNumbers(),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 50,
                          child: Column(
                            children: myNumbers.getOpponentNumbers(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex:10,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        showDeleteNumbers(1,'numberimage1'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(2,'numberimage2'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(3,'numberimage3'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(4,'numberimage4'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        attachNumber('one.png'),
                        attachNumber('two.png'),
                        attachNumber('three.png'),
                        attachNumber('four.png'),
                        attachNumber('five.png'),
                        attachNumber('six.png'),
                        attachNumber('seven.png'),
                        attachNumber('eight.png'),
                        attachNumber('nine.png'),
                        attachNumber('zero.png'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

changed the code like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'numbers.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


Numbers myNumbers = Numbers();

void main(){
  runApp(
      GameScreen()
  );
}
class GameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id ='gamescreen';
  @override
  _GameScreenState createState() => _GameScreenState();
}

class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> {
  final _auth =FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;
  final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  String collectionPath = 'users';
  String docPath;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async{
    try{
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if(user !=null){
        loggedInUser =user;
        docPath = loggedInUser.uid;
        print(docPath);
        print(collectionPath);
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }


  Expanded attachNumber(imagenumber){
    return Expanded(
      child:FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[1]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage1'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[1] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[2]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage2'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[2] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[3]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage3'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[3] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[4]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage4'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[4] =true;
            }
          });
          final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
          assetsAudioPlayer.open(
            Audio("assets/audios/click.wav"),
          );
        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: Image.asset('images/$imagenumber'),
      ),
    );
  }

  FlatButton showDeleteNumbers(statusNumber,number){
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          myNumbers.numberStatus[statusNumber] =false;
          myNumbers.buttonValues[number] = 'nonumber.png';
        });
      },
      child: Image.asset('images/'+myNumbers.buttonValues['$number']),
      //todo: _auth.signOut(); ekleyerek signout yapacaz
      //Navigator.pop(context); bir önceki ekrana dönecez;
    );
  }





  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
          title: Text('Sayı Avı Oyun Ekranı'),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection(collectionPath).document(docPath).snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Something went wrong');
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Text("Loading");
            }
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              Map<String, dynamic> userDocument  = snapshot.data.data;
              print(userDocument);
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 80,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 50,
                          child: Column(
                            children: myNumbers.getUserNumbers(),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 50,
                          child: Column(
                            children: myNumbers.getOpponentNumbers(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex:10,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        showDeleteNumbers(1,'numberimage1'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(2,'numberimage2'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(3,'numberimage3'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(4,'numberimage4'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        attachNumber('one.png'),
                        attachNumber('two.png'),
                        attachNumber('three.png'),
                        attachNumber('four.png'),
                        attachNumber('five.png'),
                        attachNumber('six.png'),
                        attachNumber('seven.png'),
                        attachNumber('eight.png'),
                        attachNumber('nine.png'),
                        attachNumber('zero.png'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Currently it gets the values of the map when i click save button, but when i go back and forward in the avd it gets null again. What may be wrong?

what i would like to do is, there is a firebase function which matches users according to their "status" in the database. when a user enters this screen, its status will be "on" in the database and when firebase function finds another user with "on" status it will make both their status "ready" or something like this. When the user's status changed to "ready" instead of showing a for example "searching for a match" screen it will change to game screen and 2 ppl will start to play turn based. So to sum up as soon as user enters this screen it should start to listen changes in its status. Also as it will be a turn based game it should continue to listen other fields later for database changes. I hope i could have explained myself.

Updated the flutter firebase code for new dependencies below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'numbers.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


Numbers myNumbers = Numbers();

void main(){
  runApp(
      GameScreen()
  );
}
class GameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id ='gamescreen';
  @override
  _GameScreenState createState() => _GameScreenState();
}

class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> {
  final _auth =FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User loggedInUser;
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final String collectionPath = 'users';
  String docPath;
  DocumentReference userdoc;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }


  void getCurrentUser() async{
    try{
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if(user !=null){
        loggedInUser =user;
        docPath = loggedInUser.uid;
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }


  Expanded attachNumber(imagenumber){
    return Expanded(
      child:FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[1]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage1'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[1] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[2]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage2'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[2] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[3]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage3'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[3] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[4]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage4'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[4] =true;
            }
          });
          final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
          assetsAudioPlayer.open(
            Audio("assets/audios/click.wav"),
          );
        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: Image.asset('images/$imagenumber'),
      ),
    );
  }

  FlatButton showDeleteNumbers(statusNumber,number){
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          myNumbers.numberStatus[statusNumber] =false;
          myNumbers.buttonValues[number] = 'nonumber.png';
        });
      },
      child: Image.asset('images/'+myNumbers.buttonValues['$number']),
    );
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    userdoc = _firestore.collection(collectionPath).doc(docPath);
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: userdoc.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          Map<String, dynamic> userDocument  = snapshot.data.data();
          print(collectionPath);
          print(docPath);
          print(snapshot.data);
          print(userDocument);
          return MaterialApp(
            home:Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                title: Text('Sayı Avı Oyun Ekranı'),
              ),
              body:Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 80,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 50,
                          child: Column(
                            children: myNumbers.getUserNumbers(),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 50,
                          child: Column(
                            children: myNumbers.getOpponentNumbers(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex:10,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        showDeleteNumbers(1,'numberimage1'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(2,'numberimage2'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(3,'numberimage3'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(4,'numberimage4'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        attachNumber('one.png'),
                        attachNumber('two.png'),
                        attachNumber('three.png'),
                        attachNumber('four.png'),
                        attachNumber('five.png'),
                        attachNumber('six.png'),
                        attachNumber('seven.png'),
                        attachNumber('eight.png'),
                        attachNumber('nine.png'),
                        attachNumber('zero.png'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

You can see there are 4 prints to check if i am getting the data correctly. Currently when i run the app it shows

I/flutter (15703): users
I/flutter (15703): viPK8SpL9MOIV2bQqGzBkKVdYAk2
I/flutter (15703): Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
I/flutter (15703): null

The 4th one shouldnt supposed to be null, when i click "save" button in android studio i get

I/flutter (15703): users
I/flutter (15703): viPK8SpL9MOIV2bQqGzBkKVdYAk2
I/flutter (15703): Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
I/flutter (15703): {password: 123456, lose: 0, win: 0, email: faruk@durusoy.net, status: ready}

Which is the correct result.

Comment: maybe add some other widget like CircularProgressIndicator, it might be the error since the data is still loading your stream didnt return any widgets

Comment: @Reign changed the code like above, when i click save button it gets all the values in the database but when i click back and forward in the avd it receives null.

Comment: Try using uid directly in the stream. Like _auth.currentUser().uid in stream doc path.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `data()` on `snapshots()`'s result in StreamBuilder.

```dart
var userDocument = snapshot.data.data();
```

Refer this: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes

Comment: changed the code like above, when i click save button it gets all the values in the database but when i click back and forward in the avd it receives null.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you elaborate on the flow?

Comment: when i click save button in android studio i receive all the info in console like this I/flutter ( 5096): {password: 123456, lose: 0, win: 0, email: faruk@gmail.com, status: off} but when i click back button in android virtual device and then re-enter this screen(dart file) it receives null. It is also same at first load. It just works when i click save button in android studio which is kinda weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you **Back to previous screen** the `initState and getCurrentUser()` function is not call again and `docPath is null` so you should call this function from Build or make another way to call it and get `docPath`

Comment: i back and then re-enter this screen, still doesnt call. It only works just once when i save the code.

Comment: when i put getCurrentUser() under widget build it gets docpath and collection path twice (i print them in console) but still getting null, docpath is not null, the snapshot data is null.

Answer (score 0):

first you should call the initState then dispose it. because every time that you run the page or update it you will call the `initState()` and that is why you lose all the data again maybe. the code is like this:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   getCurrentUser();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // : implement dispose
   getCurrentUser();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

if that didn't help read this code. i had this problem because of `QuerySnapshot` and `DocumentSnapShot`

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(

        stream: Firestore.instance.collection("MyTodos").snapshots(),

        builder: (context, snapshots) {

          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
            itemCount: snapshots.data.documents.length,
           
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

              DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                  snapshots.data.documents[index];

              return Card(              
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                  elevation: 2.0,
                  child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(documentSnapshot.data["todoTitle"]),                     
                  ),               
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
```

according to you error .I changed your code to this and you can find more on this link https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final users = _firestore.collection(collectionPath).document(docPath);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
          title: Text('Sayı Avı Oyun Ekranı'),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: users.snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Something went wrong');
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Text("Loading");
            }
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              Map<String, dynamic> userDocument  = snapshot.data.documents;
              print(userDocument);
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 80,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 50,
                          child: Column(
                            children: myNumbers.getUserNumbers(),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 50,
                          child: Column(
                            children: myNumbers.getOpponentNumbers(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex:10,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        showDeleteNumbers(1,'numberimage1'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(2,'numberimage2'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(3,'numberimage3'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(4,'numberimage4'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        attachNumber('one.png'),
                        attachNumber('two.png'),
                        attachNumber('three.png'),
                        attachNumber('four.png'),
                        attachNumber('five.png'),
                        attachNumber('six.png'),
                        attachNumber('seven.png'),
                        attachNumber('eight.png'),
                        attachNumber('nine.png'),
                        attachNumber('zero.png'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I really can't understand what kind of app you want to make. but i think if you use `ListView.builder` you can know the index of the widget that you have made.

Comment: and be sure you cleaned your flutter write this in terminal `flutter clean`

Comment: Added some info about what i want to achieve.

Comment: the way that you want to make this page is so wrong you should try to separate the UI and the logic. `be careful about firebase when you trying to use it inside flutter UI. because  if you make any small bug you will be charged double price because of requesting to much time `. I updated your code to this.

Comment: CollectionReference users = _firestore.collection(collectionPath).document(docPath); doesnt work, it says a value type of documentreference cannot be assigned to collectionreference it may work if i make just CollectionReference users = _firestore.collection(collectionPath) but i dont want it as it will grab all the users from the database and it will be waste of bandwidth (at least my quess is this)

Comment: then why you don't use   "FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where(uid)"

Comment: Also i saw someone just having the same error here: https://fantashit.com/flutter-firestore-streambuilder-error/ he fixed his problem running setstate after getting uid.

Comment: the fields in the document will change, they are not specific, for example like a chat application.

Comment: you should know new version use `QuerySnapshot` type for `StreamBuilder`

Comment: you must to know the new package version that released after August they changed a lot of functionality and syntax so you should refresh your knowledge about `Firestore`. and still you couldn't tell us what kind of result you want to achieve or how to store your data in database, that is why I thought you want above code i really still confused lol

Comment: for the error delete the `CollectionReference` replace it with final

Comment: Ahmet i updated the dependencies for the latest version and made the changes according to that (check above)

Comment: 1- you have to change that to `QuerySnapshot` and `DocumentSnapShot` like how i did to your code in above. 2- test getCurrentUser in both `initState` and `getCurrentUser()` by using print so that you going to be sure that you send the data before calling other functions 3- be sure that your map is working when you convert your data into it.

Answer (score 0):

After trying ahmed's answers and not having a solution i decided to rearrange my code just like here https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview and it finally worked. Also upgraded all of my dependencies.

Here is my final code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'numbers.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';


Numbers myNumbers = Numbers();

void main(){
  runApp(
      GameScreen()
  );
}

class GameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id ='gamescreen';

  @override
  _GameScreenState createState() => _GameScreenState();
}

class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> {
  bool _initialized = false;
  bool _error = false;

  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {
      // Wait for Firebase to initialize and set `_initialized` state to true
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      setState(() {
        _initialized = true;
      });
    } catch(e) {
      // Set `_error` state to true if Firebase initialization fails
      setState(() {
        _error = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeFlutterFire();
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  final _auth =FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User loggedInUser;
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final String collectionPath = 'users';
  String docPath;
  DocumentReference userdoc;


  void getCurrentUser() async{
    try{
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if(user !=null){
        loggedInUser =user;
        docPath = loggedInUser.uid;
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }


  Expanded attachNumber(imagenumber){
    return Expanded(
      child:FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[1]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage1'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[1] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[2]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage2'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[2] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[3]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage3'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[3] =true;
            }else if(!myNumbers.numberStatus[4]){
              myNumbers.buttonValues['numberimage4'] = imagenumber;
              myNumbers.numberStatus[4] =true;
            }
          });
          final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
          assetsAudioPlayer.open(
            Audio("assets/audios/click.wav"),
          );
        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: Image.asset('images/$imagenumber'),
      ),
    );
  }

  FlatButton showDeleteNumbers(statusNumber,number){
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          myNumbers.numberStatus[statusNumber] =false;
          myNumbers.buttonValues[number] = 'nonumber.png';
        });
      },
      child: Image.asset('images/'+myNumbers.buttonValues['$number']),
    );
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    userdoc = _firestore.collection(collectionPath).doc(docPath);
    if(_error) {
      return Text('error-game', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    }

    // Show a loader until FlutterFire is initialized
    if (!_initialized) {
      return Text('Loading', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    }
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: userdoc.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          Map<String, dynamic> userDocument  = snapshot.data.data();
          print(collectionPath);
          print(docPath);
          print(snapshot.data);
          print(userDocument);
          return MaterialApp(
            home:Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                title: Text('Sayı Avı Oyun Ekranı'),
              ),
              body:Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 80,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 50,
                          child: Column(
                            children: myNumbers.getUserNumbers(),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 50,
                          child: Column(
                            children: myNumbers.getOpponentNumbers(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex:10,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        showDeleteNumbers(1,'numberimage1'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(2,'numberimage2'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(3,'numberimage3'),
                        showDeleteNumbers(4,'numberimage4'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        attachNumber('one.png'),
                        attachNumber('two.png'),
                        attachNumber('three.png'),
                        attachNumber('four.png'),
                        attachNumber('five.png'),
                        attachNumber('six.png'),
                        attachNumber('seven.png'),
                        attachNumber('eight.png'),
                        attachNumber('nine.png'),
                        attachNumber('zero.png'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```